# show that if $ n-1$ and $n+1$ are both primes and $n>4$, then $\phi(n) \leq n/3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $n-1$ and $n+1$ are both primes and $n>4$, then $\phi(n)$ is less than or equal to $n/3$

I tried a few cases
If $n=6$, $n-1=5$, and $n+1=7$ then $~\phi(6)=2=n/3$

If $n=12$, $n-1=11$, and $n+1=13$ then  $~\phi(12)=4=n/3$

$\phi(n)=n(1-1/p_1)(1-1/p_2)...(1-1/p_k)$

Comment: What can you say about a number $n > 4$ such that $n-1$ and $n+1$ are both primes? Can it be odd? What remainders modulo $3$ are possible?

Comment: n must be even, and from the examples, n=6k. So n is congruent to 0 (mod 3)

Comment: Can you prove that $n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$?

Comment: Combine the hints: $n$ has a factor of 2 and a factor of 3. What does this say about $\phi(n)$?

Comment: It does not work for all n=6k though. When n=24, n+1=25, not prime. Now I'm not sure what to do

Comment: @Kara That $n = 6k$ is a _necessary_ condition for both $n-1$ and $n+1$ to be primes. We're simply not interested at all in those $n=6k$ for which at least one of the neighbouring numbers is composite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show that $$\phi(n)\leq \frac{n}{3}$$

If $n>4$, with $n-1$ and $n+1$ both being primes,

Now since $n-1$ is a prime $p =(n-1)> 3$

And therefore odd, it follows that, $$(n-1)+1=n, \text{ is even}$$

Likewise we know that at least one of $3$ successive integers, must be divisible by $3$.

Now looking at the integers $\{ n-1,n,n+1 \}$ we see that $n-1$ and $n+1$ are primes

So there only divisors are $1$ and themselves

Thus if $3$ divides $n-1$ or $n+1$, we must have either $3=n-1$ or that $3=n+1$

But we know that $n-1>3$ and $n+1>5$, so we see neither of these can happen

And thus $3$ must divide $n$

So we have that $3\mid n$ and $2\mid n$

Now we need to show that $$\phi(n)\leq \frac{n}{3}$$

Or equivalently $$\frac{\phi(n)}{n} \leq \frac{1}{3}$$

Or $$\prod_{p\mid n}(1-\frac{1}{p})\leq \frac{1}{3}$$

But since $2\mid n$ and $3\mid n$ we can re-write this as,

$$\frac{1}{3}\prod_{p\mid n}_{p\ne 2}_{p\ne 3}(1-\frac{1}{p})=(1-\frac{1}{3})(1-\frac{1}{2})\prod_{p\mid n}_{p\ne 2}_{p\ne 3}(1-\frac{1}{p})\leq \frac{1}{3}$$

$$\iff \frac{1}{3}\prod_{p\mid n}_{p\ne 2}_{p\ne 3}(1-\frac{1}{p})\leq \frac{1}{3}$$

$$\iff \prod_{p\mid n}_{p\ne 2}_{p\ne 3}(1-\frac{1}{p})\leq 1$$

Which is clearly true,

Thus if $n>4$, with $n-1$ and $n+1$ both being primes

$$\phi(n)\leq \frac{n}{3}$$

As required.